# how to generate data coming from flask to json data format in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, flask

i am trying to retreive data coming flask and parsing that data into json format

```
           df_in_jsObject = JSON.parse(df);
           console.log(df_in_jsObject);
```

I am receiving data in this formate

```
                0: "X"
                1: "Y"
                2: "Z"
```

But i want the data to be in this format

```
            var df_in_jsObject = [{

                "value": "X"
            },
            {

                "value": "Y"
            },
            {

                "value": "Z"
            }
            ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the JSON coming from flask is in array format but you need it in an array of objects format, then you could do this:

```js
df_in_jsObject = JSON.parse(df).map(value => ({value}));
const newJson = JSON.stringify(df_in_jsObject);
console.log(newJson);
```

Comment: hey @Collierre the output is now coming lie this value: "X" but not in this format "value": "Y" that is value should also be in double quotes

Comment: So wait are you trying to get JSON as your input, and then parse it into a different JSON string as your output?

Comment: yes , @Collierre i want the output should be like "value": "X"

Comment: So you're getting JSON data from flask in one format, then you want to convert it to a different form of JSON? Why is it that you need JSON as the output format?

Comment: Ok well if that's what you want to do I've modified my answer to convert back into JSON.

Answer (score 0):

[JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) has tow parameters, the second is `reviver`, which we can transform it's format before being returned. Like this,

```
var df = '["x", "y", "z"]';

var df_in_jsObject = JSON.parse(df, function(key, val) {
    if (key === "") { // in top layer, key is empty string, return val directly
        return val;
    }
    return {value: val}
})
console.log(df_in_jsObject);
// Output: [ { value: 'x' }, { value: 'y' }, { value: 'z' } ]

var standardJsonString = JSON.stringify(df_in_jsObject);
console.log(standardJsonString);
// Output: "[{"value":"x"},{"value":"y"},{"value":"z"}]"
```

Comment: Hey @Pylon i want output in this way // Output: [ { "value": "x" }, { "value": "y" }, { "value": "z" } ]

Comment: @ParthTiwari In JavaScript, Quotes of the JSON key can be omitted. However, you could get standard JSON string by `JSON.stringify(obj)`